# Enterprise JavaBeans (EJB) module does not have any enterprise beans configured

Tags: glassfish, ejb, websphere

I am migrating Java EE Application from glassfish to Websphere Application Server, I got error below:

> The Penjualan.war Enterprise JavaBeans (EJB) module does not have any enterprise beans configured.
>       at com.ibm.ws.ejbcontainer.runtime.AbstractEJBRuntime.startModule(AbstractEJBRuntime.java:731)
>       at com.ibm.ws.ejbcontainer.runtime.SharedEJBRuntimeImpl.startModule(SharedEJBRuntimeImpl.java:338)
>       at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.EJBContainerImpl.start(EJBContainerImpl.java:3576)
>       at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.start(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1177)
>       at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.fireDeployedObjectStart(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:1370)
>       at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedModuleImpl.start(DeployedModuleImpl.java:639)
>       at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.start(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:968)
>       at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.startApplication(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:776)
>       at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.startApplicationDynamically(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1379)
>       at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.start(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:2189)
>       at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.start(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:435)
>       at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitImpl.start(CompositionUnitImpl.java:123)
>       at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.start(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:378)
>       at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.access$500(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:126)
>       at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl$1.run(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:653)
>       at com.ibm.ws.security.auth.ContextManagerImpl.runAs(ContextManagerImpl.java:5387)
>       at com.ibm.ws.security.auth.ContextManagerImpl.runAsSystem(ContextManagerImpl.java:5603)
>       at com.ibm.ws.security.core.SecurityContext.runAsSystem(SecurityContext.java:255)
>       at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.startCompositionUnit(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:667)
>       at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.startCompositionUnit(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:611)
>       at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.startApplication(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1269)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:88)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:613)
>       at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:68)
>       at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor14.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:613)
>       at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:287)
>       at javax.management.modelmbean.RequiredModelMBean$4.run(RequiredModelMBean.java:1256)
>       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:252)
>       at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
>       at javax.management.modelmbean.RequiredModelMBean.invokeMethod(RequiredModelMBean.java:1250)

What should I do ?

Note:

- there is no ejb-jar.xml on my war
- the application runs well on glassfish

Comment: What version of WebSphere?

Comment: Also check if you have web.xml and if present, if it has version 3 or higher.

Comment: Thanks for fast response SteveC and Gas. I have solved my problem with put metadata-complete="true" on web.xml. My WAS version is 8.5.5.6